# LazyModules in RocketChip

Tags: riscv, chisel

For a while, I've been trying to learn about `LazyModule` abstract class and `diplomacy` package in general. The simplest conclusion would be that objects of classes children of LazyModule are instantiated only when they are accessed for the first time. (Please do correct me if I am wrong)

In [RocketTile.scala](https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip/blob/master/src/main/scala/tile/RocketTile.scala) there are multiple examples `LazyModule` usage, such as:
`scala
  lazy val module = new LazyModuleImp(this) {...`

What happens when a value is not declared `lazy` and it is still assigned a `LazyModule`?

In other words, does the "laziness" of the created value come from it inheriting from `LazyModule` or we must put `lazy` in front to get the expected behavior?

Answer (score 1):

I can't go into a detailed explanation but will offer this:  `lazy` means Scala-language deferred initialization.  The `lazy val module` is only executed/evaluated once it is needed.  It works out well for the use case presented because the hardware description is only evaulated after design configuration is complete.

I wrote this blog post a while back.  It may offer additional insight:

http://blog.edmondcote.com/2017/04/parameters-and-lazy-modules.html